Return a list of positions of all possible occurrences of a character in a string
In Python how do you get a list of all possible occurrences of a character or a substring in a given string
Input: "This is a string" , "s"
Output: [3,6,10]
Explanation: Returns the positions of s in the string
Input: "How do you do?" , " "
Output: [3,6,10]
Explanation: Returns the positions of \s in the string
Input: "Nothing" , "a"
Output: []
Explanation: There are no a in the given string
I tried using find(), index(), but they provide an int of the first occurrence and provide -1 if its not present
Searched on gfg but it showed for only one occurrence and not a list

This question is similar to: How to find char in string and get all the indexes?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A simple iteration can do it:
sentence = "This is a string"
s = "s"
print([idx for idx, i in enumerate(sentence) if i==s])


You can iterate over the characters in the input string and add the position to an array which you can return.
An other possible solutions is to use regular expressions
